# Alternative Anchor Tag For When Javascript Is Not Enabled

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is possible to have an anchor tag have a different "href" attribute when javascript is not enabled.

For Example:

Javascript Enabled:

```
<a href="#news">News</a>
```

Javascript Not Enabled:

```
<a href="news.html">News</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the javascript enabled attribute in a `data-xxxx`, and then use javascript to replace the `href` with `data-xxxx`.

For example, in HTML you could use

```
<a href="news.html" data-js-href="#news">News</a>
```

And in javascript, you could do

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-js-href]');
for (var i=0; i<links.length; ++i) {
    links[i].setAttribute('href', links[i].getAttribute('data-js-href'));
}
```